# Difference between reserved words and keywords?

Tags: c++, keyword, reserved-words

What are the differences between reserved words and keywords in C++?

Is 'main' a reserved word or a keyword?

Comment: Not quite exact dupe, because this specifies C++, which makes the answer more precise. The keywords of C++ are the words listed in 2.11, *and nothing more* (unless there's some other part of the standard which lists more keywords, but I doubt it). The answer that says "most keywords are reserved words and vice versa" is wrong about the "vice versa" in the case of C++, since the infinity of reserved names containing a double-underscore are *not* keywords in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I could think of that might differentiate the two is if a word was reserved for future use (i.e. not a keyword, but also not allowed for use).  However, I couldn't think of an exapmle off the top of my head...

Main is not a keyword per se, but it is usually required by C, C++, C#, and similar languages as the beginning execution point of your app.  These langauges each define the role of main in the corresponding language specification.

Comment: In certain other cases, a keyword can also be used as an identifier because the compiler is able to disambiguate between them based on context.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, I'd say a keyword has to have a meaning. Some languages have reserved words that are not actually keywords. (Java reserves goto, even though it does not have a goto statement, for example.)

And main is just a function name that is treated specially.